# talkback is announcing hidden views

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am adding accessibility to an app and I am using google's talkback for testing accessibility and I am unable to block certain views from being selected.

Besides removing all listeners and focusability, is there any better way to disable views from obtaining focus when they are hidden on the screen... ie having a "drawer" open and disabling the selection of items in the content container? It seems like there should be a cleaner solution to this or maybe a fix is required on the talkback team's side.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to disable Talkback announcements permanently?

Comment: You can set `importantForAccessibility="2"` for a View to let `Talkback` ignore it. But the View will still be focusable/clickable. Since `DrawerLayout` is a descendent of `View` class, `importantForAccessibility` property should work for it. See the documentation for View class to read on the possible values that this property can take: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:importantForAccessibility). Still, your question is not very clear in regards to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solution only works for API level >= 16 however talkback has been in android prior to API level 16.  How is the question not clear? I just want to disable talkback "announcements" when my app is in certain states for certain views. Besides my example of a drawer... another example is when certain views are set to invisible they will still be "announced" and i would like to prevent this without changing visibility to gone.

Comment: Its strange that invisible views are being announced. You can try another approach: Use `AccessibilityDelegate` (also available in support v4 - AccessibilityDelegateCompat). Create an AD object and override `onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info)`. Call the super method if the View('host') is visible. Use this object as an argument to `yourView.setAccessibilityDelegate(ad_object)`. See if that helps.

Comment: thanks user! your advice combined with ViewCompat solved my problem. If you want to post an answer for me to accept that would be great!

Comment: That's great. I'll post an answer later on today.

Answer (score 3):

Look into `AccessibilityDelegateCompat` available in support-v4 library - [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat.html).

Create an instance of `AccessibilityDelegateCompat` and override the following method:

```
@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, 
                                         AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {

    // Check if 'host' is visible or not before calling the super method
    if (host.getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
    }
}
```

Finally, use static method `ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(View, AccessibilityDelegateCompat)` for the views that are invisible.